# Default .yml file from GitHub from does not work

Tags: laravel, github, yaml, phpunit, github-actions

I'm trying to run phpunit tests through GitHub actions.
I use `.yml` file that GitHub creates by default for Laravel projects but it does not seem worked.
Here it is (looks good):

```yaml
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Setup
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
        with:
          php-version: '8.1'
      - name: Copy.env
        run: |
          php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
      - name: Generate key
        run: php artisan key:generate
      - name: Directory Permissions
        run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
      - name: Create Database
        run: |
          mkdir -p database
          touch database/database.sqlite
      - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
        env:
          DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
          DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

But when I do `git push` I got:
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You have an error on the "copy" step, it cannot find the file, so do you have the `.env.example` file? I would also recommend to use `cp .env.example .env` so if it truly fails, the step will fail and not pass like in here

Comment: @matiaslauriti of course I have. This file is a default file for all Laravel projects. I’ll try `cp` command today. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I compared my script with the default one by GitHub and found that somehow I missed 1 step: `uses: actions/checkout@v2`.
That's why the script could not find `.env.example` file in the directory.
Now everything works fine.

Comment: You missed the action that literally does the `git checkout`, I assumed `shivammathur/setup-php` was doing so...